# S3 file to local using luigi raises UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-s3, luigi

I am copying a `pdf` file  to local, using the following piece of code:

```python
with self.input_target().open('r') as r:
    with self.output_target().open('w') as w:
       for line in r: 
           w.write(line)
```

Which is based in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33332058/luigi-pipeline-beginning-in-s3) question (kind of)

But when I execute that code I get the following:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 11:
      invalid continuation byte
```

I tried this other approach, without good results:

```
   with self.input_target().open('r') as r, self.output_target().open('w') as w:                                                                                                                        
       w.write(r.read())
```

What is the correct way of doing it?

Comment: could you prepare a minimal example to reproduce it and the pdf?

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use the format kwarg luigi.format.Nop to Target to indicate that it is a binary file that is being read.

e.g.

```
def output(self):
    return LocalTarget(target, format=luigi.format.Nop)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're dealing with a binary file as if it was text - but it's not. You probably need to do something like this:

```
with self.input().open('r') as i, self.output().open('w') as o:
    o.write(i.read())
```

(not tested!)

Also, I think you may find this answer useful: [Python writing binary files, bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16630789/python-writing-binary-files-bytes)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I didn 't work. Same error: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 11: invalid continuation byte` `:(` I will update the question

Comment: try `open('rb')` and `open('wb')`

Comment: Do you know the encoding of the pdf file? If it's Latin-1, then you should read it as such: `self.input_target().open('r', encoding="ISO-8859-1")`.

Comment: `luigi` doesn` t support the `encoding` argument

Answer (score 0):

I ended using `luigi.s3.S3Client`and the method `get` which copies a binary file from/to the `s3`.

Snippet of code:

import luigi

```
class ATask(luigi.Task):
    s3_path = luigi.Parameter()
    local_path = luigi.Parameter()
    ...

    def run(self):
        client = luigi.s3.S3Client()
        client.get(s3_path, local_path)  ## This gets the file
        ...
```

I think that the underlying reason is that `luigi` uses `boto` for getting/putting files from/to the `s3`. (As you can see in the source code)